# SQL Server join to same table multiple times with the on clause having an and

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I am trying to take multiple rows of data and combine them into one row.  The input data looks like this:

```
prop_name          tocid    str_val
Year              181030    10
Billing Cycle     181030    2
Month             181030    08
```

I want the output to be:

```
10    2    08
```

I am trying this code:

```
select 
pv1.str_val
,pv2.str_val
,p3.str
from propdef pd
    inner join propval pv1 on pd.prop_id = pv1.prop_id and pd.prop_name = 'Year'
    inner join propval pv2 on pd.prop_id = pv2.prop_id and pd.prop_name = 'Billing Cycle'
    inner join propval pv3 on pd.prop_id = pv3.prop_id and pd.prop_name = 'Month'
where 
    pv1.tocid in (181030)
```

This does not return any data.  I thought I was supposed to be able to do the inner join to the same table.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do a double full outer join.

Comment: PIVOT technique such as conditional aggregation will preform a lot better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for joins:

```
SELECT  tocid,
        MIN(CASE WHEN prop_name = 'Year' THEN str_val END) [Year],
        MIN(CASE WHEN prop_name = 'Billing Cycle' THEN str_val END) [Billing Cycle],
        MIN(CASE WHEN prop_name = 'Month' THEN str_val END) [Month]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY tocid;
```

Comment: just probably need the where for the tocid = 181030.  Man you are fast I was just about to start typing :)

Comment: @Matt I thought about it, but decided to post a general answer for every `tocid`. With that `WHERE` there would be no need for the `GROUP BY`